# What NSExtensionActivationRule key Netflix uses?

Tags: ios, action, share, netflix

Someone knows what NSExtensionActivationRule key Netflix uses to share content? I've tried all of them, from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html) and couldn't manager to make my Action Extension shows on share content.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found it.

To make your App Extension to be shown on share content of Netflix, you will need two Rules:

- NSExtensionActivationSupportsText
- NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount

Only them your app will shows up.
Answering my own question in case some one else need it.